# How i can write this method using Java Generics?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I'm trying to write this method using java generics :

```
public void trackUserActivity(String operation,TemplateEntity templateEntity,String user,,String entity, HistoryJpaRepository  historyJpaRepository)
{
            HistoryEntity historyEntity = new HistoryEntity();
            historyEntity.setData(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            historyEntity.setAction(operation);
            historyEntity.setEntity("TEMPLATE");
            historyEntity.setEntityJson(null);
            if(!operation.contentEquals("CREATE"))
            {
                ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
                
                String json = null;
                try {
                    json = ow.writeValueAsString(templateEntity);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                historyEntity.setEntityJson(json.getBytes());  
       
          
            } 
            historyEntity.setIdEntity(templateEntity.getId());
            historyEntity.setUser(user);       
             historyJpaRepository.save(historyEntity);
     
}
```

inside this method I have the getId() method which is common to multiple object types, I tried to create an interface with a default method with a generic type T that extends multiple classes :

```
public interface HistoryUtils <T extends LavorazioneDto,DizionarioDto,CampoDizionarioDto,FontDto,RegolaCampoDizionarioDto,TemplateEntity >{
    
  
    
    
    
    public default void trackUserActivity(String operation,T t,String user,String entity, HistoryJpaRepository  historyJpaRepository)
    {
        HistoryEntity historyEntity = new HistoryEntity();
                historyEntity.setData(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
                historyEntity.setAction(operation);
                historyEntity.setEntity(entity);
                historyEntity.setEntityJson(null);
                if(!operation.contentEquals("CREATE"))
                {
                    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
                    String json = null;
                    try {
                        json = ow.writeValueAsString(t);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    historyEntity.setEntityJson(json.toString().getBytes());
              
                }
                historyEntity.setIdEntity(t.getId());
                historyEntity.setUser(user);       
            historyJpaRepository.save(historyEntity);
        
    }
```

only that after I autowired my interface in one of the services and I try to call the interface method I get this error:
The method `trackUserActivity(String, LavorazioneDto, String, String, HistoryJpaRepository)` in the type HistoryUtils is not applicable for the arguments `(String, TemplateEntity, String, String, HistoryJpaRepository)`.
How can I write an interface that makes use of generics and extends all the classes I need?

Comment: `<T extends LavorazioneDto,DizionarioDto,CampoDizionarioDto,FontDto,RegolaCampoDizionarioDto,TemplateEntity >` doesn't make much sense to me. You should reference your interface, not all its implementations.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean, basically I have several classes in which the same method (trackUserActivity) was implemented, to save code I'm trying to create an interface using generics with a default method that allows me to reuse the same code, the thing is that inside the method I need to be able to access the getId() method which is common to all the objects from which I have extended T. I know that how I extended T is not a solution, in fact I was looking for one

Comment: Extract common methods to an interface and have all the implementations implement that interface.

Comment: @Kindermaxi show the piece of code where you are autowiring i have a feeling you forgot to actually had the generic part of the interface where you are autowiring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration

```
<T extends LavorazioneDto,DizionarioDto,CampoDizionarioDto,FontDto,RegolaCampoDizionarioDto,TemplateEntity >
```

requires `T` to extend `LavorazioneDto`, **and** to extend `DizionarioDto`, and so on. That is, it requires T to extend all these types, rather than any of these types. In type theoretic terms, T is an intersection type, not a union type. Java doesn't support union types in type bounds.

The usual solution would be to have the possible subtypes implement a common interface, and use that interface as a parameter type:

```
interface Identifiable {
    String getId();
}

class LavorazioneDto implements Identifiable {
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

interface HistoryUtils {
    public default void trackUserActivity(String operation,Identifiable t,String user,String entity, HistoryJpaRepository  historyJpaRepository) {
        t.getId(); // works just fine
    }
}
```

That is, I don't see why you are using generics in the first place, if plain old polymorphism does the job just fine.